# How to quickly generate (insecure) GPG keys?

Tags: gpg, testing, random

I'd like to automate generating at least two GPG keys for testing and demonstration purposes in a virtual machine. Because of this context I want to **make sure the key generation is fast, ideally not using or modifying `/dev/*random` at all.** For example, using the system clock as the only random source would be fine:

```
$ gpg --quick-gen-key 'alice' [options] --random-data $(date +%s)
$ sleep 2
$ gpg --quick-gen-key 'bob' [options] --random-data $(date +%s)
```

I haven't been able to find any options like this. There's [`-quick-random`](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/GnuPG-FAQ.html#it-really-takes-long-when-i-work-on-a-remote-system) and [`--debug-quick-random`](https://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/issues/detail?id=61) which are not in the `man` page, seem to be supported by `gpg`, and *just don't work.* These commands, for example, ran for several minutes before I killed them:

```
$ gpg --batch --debug-quick-random --passphrase 'alice' --quick-gen-key 'alice@example.org'
$ gpg --batch -quick-random --passphrase 'alice' --quick-gen-key 'alice@example.org'
```

Using `gpg` (GnuPG) 2.1.2.

Comment: Which route did you took in the end?

Comment: @gf_ I moved on to something else.

Answer (score 6):

You can temporarily have `/dev/random` pull from `/dev/urandom` using `rng-tools`:

```
# rngd -v -f -r /dev/urandom
```

More information here: https://madebits.github.io/#blog/2014/2014-05-30-Making-dev-random-Temporary-Faster.md

Comment: Also related is a daemon called `haveged`, I seem to recall that RHEL/CentOS have one but not the other.

Comment: How do you revert it back to more safe `/dev/urandom`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same requirement while writing my [smartcard setup program](http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/rants/2014/setting_up_an_openpgp_smartcard_with_gnupg/). During testing I would not care about entropy, and I needed to generate multiple GPG keys in a row each test.

As I described in my answer [here](http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/rants/2014/setting_up_an_openpgp_smartcard_with_gnupg/) the following script helped me speeding things up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# For testing purposes only 
# DO NOT USE THIS, THIS DOES NOT PROVIDE ENTROPY TO /dev/random, JUST BYTES

import fcntl
import time
import struct

RNDADDENTROPY=0x40085203

while True:
    random = "3420348024823049823-984230942049832423l4j2l42j"
    t = struct.pack("ii32s", 8, 32, random)
    with open("/dev/random", mode='wb') as fp:
        # as fp has a method fileno(), you can pass it to ioctl
        res = fcntl.ioctl(fp, RNDADDENTROPY, t)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: Doesn't this have a fairly large chance of resulting in identical keys? (I guess that could be counteracted by adding nano-time to the mix.)

Comment: @l0b0 I haven't noticed that, it could be. But it doesn't have to be as the system still inserts entropy during the time this is running as well. You could use the nano-time or some long cycle random number generator not depending on reading from `/dev/random`.